How to calculate temperature right from RuuviTag advertizement packet?
I have micropython code in ESP32 that reads ruuvitag with BLE. I can receive BLE advertizement packet, 31 bytes. Ruuvitag uses dataformat 5. Firmware v3.31.3+default.
Packet is this: b'\x02\x01\x06\x1b\xff\x99\x04\x05\x12\xcb5\x80\xc9\x0e\xff\xf8\xff\xfc\x03\xe0\xab\xd6\x0e\xce\xf5\xe7\xf5\xe46\x9bY'
It decodes to hex as: 02, 01, 06, 1B, FF, 99, 04, 05, 12, CB, 35, 80, C9, 0E, FF, F8, FF, FC, 03, E0, AB, D6, 0E, CE, F5, E7, F5, E4, 36, 9B, 59
As int it is: 2, 1, 6, 27, 255, 153, 4, 5, 18, 203, 53, 128, 201, 14, 255, 248, 255, 252, 3, 224, 171, 214, 14, 206, 245, 231, 245, 228, 54, 155, 89
and after removing 4 bytes to get it to 27 bytes, final payload is: FF99040512CB3580C90EFFF8FFFC03E0ABD60ECEF5E7F5E4369B59
I then take bytes 2 and 3 values and calculate temperature in celsius, and i get 10.29C. Problem is that current temperature viewed from ruuvi app is 24,07C. How should i calculate temperature to get it right?
        temp_high = payload[2]  
        temp_low = payload[3]  

        temp_16bit = (temp_high << 8) | temp_low
        temperature = temp_16bit / 100.0
        print(f"Lämpötila: {temperature:.2f} °C")


I have solved the problem. I started to excel values and found out that uncutted packet, bytes 8&9 are for temperature which i calculate like this:
temperature = (payload[8] << 8 | payload[9]) / 200.0

And humidity are bytes 10&11 and i calculate like this:
humidity = (payload[10] << 8 | payload[11]) * 0.0025

Now i get exactly same values as the app says.

Congratulations, you have re-engineered what Ruuvi wrote in his documentation. https://docs.ruuvi.com/communication/bluetooth-advertisements https://docs.ruuvi.com/communication/bluetooth-advertisements/data-format-4-url

Sometimes it says takes time to get it right when missing obious things. I cant tell any color difference in the data sheet between darkgreen and green sections. Yes, that much i am color blind. So when data sheet tells things about magic dark green section...

Not sure if I understand your comment correctly, but the dark green part marks the header of the AD structure. In your case, 0x1B as the length, 0xFF as the TAG for "manufacturer specific data" and 0x99, 0x04 as the manufacturer ID 0x0499 for "Ruuvi Innovations Ltd". The following 0x05 refers to this description: https://docs.ruuvi.com/communication/bluetooth-advertisements/data-format-5-rawv2
